# Running a .bat file continuously opens new instances of CMD?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, batch-file, cmd

Trying to run a basic .bat file on my work machine. I have a file named chrome.bat that contains only the line `start chrome`. When I enter `start chrome` into CMD or PowerShell, it opens a new window of Chrome as one would expect. When I click on the .bat file, however, new instances of CMD are continuously created, no Chrome window is opened, and I have to hold CTRL-C until the process is killed.

Any insight?

Comment: @readers: if you try to reproduce, save your work first...

Comment: OR: `taskkill /im conhost.exe` and `taskkill /im cmd.exe` : )

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out. The problem is that I named the file with the same name as the command. Renaming the file to `blah.bat` works just fine.